# returning lowercase strings from a list, without returning a value beforehand

Tags: python

I need to take a list of strings and and return them all lowercase, without returning a value. So the computer will do this for input

```
strings = ['Right', 'SAID', 'Fred']
set_lowercase(strings)
print(strings)
```

and want the answer

```
['right', 'said', 'fred']
```

this here is my code and i can give the right answers before it inputs print, but if i remove my final statement of return or print. Then when the computer goes to print, it will only print the original inputs of

```
['Right', 'SAID', 'Fred']
```

My code:

```
def set_lowercase(strings):
    """takes list of strings and converts to lowercase"""
    result = []
    strings_str = ' '.join(strings)
    for i in strings_str:
        strings_low = strings_str.lower()
        new_strings = str.lower(strings_low)
        strings = new_strings.split()
        return strings
```

I know its a bit messy and i have cleaner versions, im just trying every other version i can think of, but still receiving the same problem.

edit: My slightly cleaner version.

```
def set_lowercase(strings):
    """takes list of strings and converts to lowercase"""
    my_list = strings
    lower_string = str.lower(' ' .join(my_list))
    return lower_string.split()
```

Comment: Start with the cleanest version and post that. It is very likely that you will understand the solution if you start with that.

Comment: You code is very wrong. You do not need a loop, `strings_str.lower().split()` does all the job you need.

Comment: maybe `strings = map(lambda x: x.lower(), strings)` is good enough as your entire function.

Comment: Have you considered `def set_lowercase(strings): strings[:] = list(map(str.lower, strings))`? Fewer lines mean fewer places to go wrong, as your code does more than once, in a variety of ways.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 good job targeting the reference

Comment: `strings = ' '.join(strings).lower().split()` It's work for you.

Comment: Note that joining and splitting on space only works if you can guarantee that none of the strings in the list contain any whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def set_lowercase(strings):
    for i in range(len(strings)):
        strings[i] = strings[i].lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function.

```
def set_lowercase(strings):
    return [string.lower() for string in strings]
```

Answer (score 0):

A return is not necessary, `strings[:]` updates the list in place:

```
def set_lowercase(strings):
    strings[:] = [string.lower() for string in strings]

strings = ['Right', 'SAID', 'Fred']
set_lowercase(strings)
print(strings)
```

This will display:

```
['right', 'said', 'fred']
```